# como capturar los datos de un form para mostrarlos en un documento pdf

Tags: php, base-de-datos, pdf

Quiero generar un documento el cual capture los datos de un formulario y al momento de enviarlos cree un documento pdf con los datos ya registrados y una plantilla del documento ej: mi nombre es `$nombre` `$apellidos` de nacionalidad `$nacionalidad`...

En estos momentos estoy utilizando `fpdf` pero no se como integrar una plantilla para el documento ni tampoco capturar los datos del form para integrarlos en el documento.

```
<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

...

$html = '<p>PODER SIMPLE Don (ña) ________________________, nacionalidad_________, estado civil__________ profesión u oficio___________________ RUT_____________________, domiciliado en _________,Comuna de__________________, viene en otorgar poder a don(doña) __________________________,nacionalidad_________, estado civil_________, profesión u oficio________________ RUT: _______________, domiciliado_________, para que en nombre y representación del poderdante, tramite ante el Colegio de Abogados de Chile, procedimiento disciplinario en contra del abogado colegiado don ______________________ NOMBRE FIRMA</p>';

// Creación del objeto de la clase heredada
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, utf8_decode(''));
$pdf->WriteHTML($html);

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Tambien me gustaría saber como en el documento puedo mostrar las Ñ y las tildes ya que integrando este código `utf8_decode` aun me sale con errores.

Answer (score 0):

**Information Preprocess in Real time**
Para capturar la información de un formulario o elementos html puedes usar directamente funciones Javascript de tu Form, los capturas en variables específicas para llevarlas de tu plantilla de de Form a funciones internas de tu programa donde podrás pre-procesar la información que recoges de los elementos del Form.

Al momento de realizar un envío del Form programas un proceso adjunto al envío del Form para crear el pdf con las variables que recuperaste al momento de llenado del formulario.

**Capturar info:** Existen muchas formas de hacerlo.

```
/*the specific input*/
var inputID = document.getElementById('inputID');

/*add a listener to the object for blur*/
inputID.addEventListener('blur',function(){
    //the value attribute is the way to get what the user entered.
    console.log(inputID.value);
});
```